# Recorre un .CSV editar contenido y guardar usando php

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Mi pregunta es como lograr leer y mostrar un **.csv** en una tabla html usando **php**.

Este es parte del código que he logrado hasta hoy:

```
    <table border="1">
        <caption>Enlaces</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Enlace</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $handle = fopen("datos.csv", "r");
            while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
                $num = count($data);
                print "";
                echo '<td>' . $data[0] . '</td></tr><tr>
                      <td>' . $data[1] . '</td>';
            }
            fclose($handle);
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Asumiendo que el

> datos.csv

Contiene muchas cifras en este formato :

```
Google.com,2012
Yahoo.con,2013
Facebook.com,2014
```

En total son mas de 100 lineas, en el código que muestro la tabla no queda bien acomodada y no se si es la manera correcta de leer y mostrar en una tabla.

También me gustaría ponerle paginación para no mostrar toda la lista de una ves.

Comment: No sería mejor cargarlo a una base de datos y que saques la información de la base de datos con un query? Tengo un código para eso, si quieres mañana te lo paso :)

Comment: Claro que es mejor de esa manera . pero este tema se trata de leer un .csv usando PHP para luego mostrarlo . igual gracias por el dato . saludos cordiales

Comment: Ya, sobre lo de paginación... Puedes utilizar este plugin de jQuery www.datatables.net, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal el marcado de la tabla, por eso se mueven las filas.

Debes abrir y cerrar las filas dentro del bucle, en cada iteración y no antes.

```
<table border="1">
    <caption>Enlaces</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Enlace</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
        $handle = fopen("datos.csv", "r");
        while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $data[0] . '</td><td>' . $data[1] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        fclose($handle);
        ?>
</table>
```

---

Para la paginación es tan sencillo como leer primero todo el fichero y después mostrar solo la porción que corresponde:

```
<?php
    // leemos el fichero y metemos todo en un array
    $handle = fopen("datos.csv", "r");
    $data = array();
    while ($linea = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
        $data[] = $linea;
    }
    fclose($handle);


    $elementos_por_pagina = 10;
    // obtenemos el parámetro de la página actual ó 0 (cero) por defecto
    $pagina = isset($_GET['pagina'])?$_GET['pagina']:0;
    // el primer elemento depende de la pagina a mostrar
    $inicio = $pagina * $elementos_por_pagina;
    // nos aseguramos que no nos pasamos del total de elementos
    $final = min(count($data), $inicio + $elementos_por_pagina);
    // almacenamos el html generado para mostrarlo todo junto al final
    $lineas_html = '';
    for ($i = $inicio; $i < $final; $i++) {
        $lineas_html .= '<tr>';
        $lineas_html .= '<td>' . $data[$i][0] . '</td><td>' . $data[$i][1] . '</td>';
        $lineas_html .= '</tr>';
    }

    // enlaces paginado
    $paginado_html = '<ul class="paginado">'; 
    // creamos un enlace a cada página, tantos como se necesiten según el tamaño del fichero y cuantos $elementos_por_pagina usemos
    for ($i=0;$i*$elementos_por_pagina<count($data);$i++){
        $paginado_html .= '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'"> '.$i.' </a></li>';
    } 
    $paginado_html .= '</ul>'; 
?>

<table border="1">
    <caption>Enlaces</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Enlace</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>
    <?= $lineas_html ?>
</table>
    <?= $paginado_html ?>
```

No copies y pegues el código, quizá no funcione completamente, es sólo un esquema para que compruebes lo sencillo del planteamiento inicial, tras entenderlo puedes complicarte todo lo que desees con más funcionalidades.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación